# Table cell click event work with an f:ajax tag

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, uirepeat

I have been playing around with JSF and ui:repeat to create a simple dynamic table.  My next step in teh process is to allow each cell in the table to be clickable/edited and started to tie in f:ajax around an h:outputlabel.  This is where my dilemma begins because I would like the entire cell to be clickable, not just the contents/text of the cell and I haven't found a way to make the cell respond to an ajax click.

I have been doing a lot of searching but haven't found the direction that I need or a JSF expert to say "That's not possible".

So, my questions are:

1. is there a jsf component that can be used that can work with f:ajax tag and can also be formatted to fit a table cell?
2. is there a way to make the actual table cell click event work with an f:ajax tag or something similar.

As always thanks for the input and suggestions!

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard JSF component which generates a `<td>` with an `onclick` attribute.

Your best bet is to include a `<h:commandLink>` in the table cell and let it span the entire space of the table cell by setting its CSS `display` property to `block`.

```
<td>
    <h:commandLink ... style="display:block;">
        <f:ajax ... />
        <h:outputLabel ... />
        ...
    </h:commandLink>
</td>
```

*(note that best practice is to specify CSS classes in a separate `.css` file and to use `styleClass` instead; the above is just examplary)*

This gives the enduser the impression that the entire table cell is clickable.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and answer.  It Works beautifully!!